# Migrating from PostGIS 1.5 to 3.2: need to replace geography_typmod_dims

Tags: postgis, update, geography

I can't find a replacement function for `geography_typmod_dims` which is used in an old application.

In 1.5 there were:
`geography_typmod_dims`, `_in`, `_out`, `_srid` and `_type`.

In 3.2 I find only:
`geography_typmod_in` and `_out`.

Comment: I do not really understand these typmods but your function seems to be dropped 10 years ago in PostGIS 2.0 https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1640.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an old example](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/532) showing `geography_typmod_dims` being used to get the coordinate dimensions of a field from the `pg_attribute` typmod for the field. That is being used to create the `coord_dimension` field in the `postgis.geography_columns` view.

Current PostGIS support for geography designates dimensions using [M, Z or ZM suffixes on type names](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Create_Geography_Tables).

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  blank geography(POINT, 4326),
  m     geography(POINTM, 4326),
  z     geography(POINTZ, 4326),
  zm    geography(POINTZM, 4326)
);
```

```
db=> SELECT f_table_name, f_geography_column,
            coord_dimension, type
     FROM geography_columns;
 f_table_name | f_geography_column | coord_dimension |  type   
--------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------
 test         | blank              |               2 | Point
 test         | m                  |               3 | PointM
 test         | z                  |               3 | PointZ
 test         | zm                 |               4 | PointZM
(4 rows)
```

You should be able to replace uses of `geography_typmod_dims` one of two ways:

1. **If you know the table and column you are dealing with**, look it up in the coord_dimensions field of the `geography_columns` view.
2. **If you need to check the dimensions of a geography object**, perhaps you can check the return from [`ST_Summary`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Summary.html) for `Z`, `M` or `ZM` and figure out the cases that apply to your application. Looking at the [PostGIS Function Support Matrix](http://www.postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_TypeFunctionMatrix), `ST_Summary` is the only function I see that might help you for geography.